# Java GUI designer for Eclipse, free commercial use

Tags: gratis, java, gui, eclipse, gui-builder

What are the current state of the art FREE Java Gui design tool for commercial use?

Requirements for the software:

1. Provides a good GUI for pulling things together
2. Java-based
3. Free for commercial use
4. Can be integrated with Eclipse
5. user-friendly with up-to-dated modules
6. active community on questions and answers
7. open-sourced is preferred
8. Maintained (updated at least once every two years)
9. Desktop application. (for Ubuntu and Window)

   10. Last but not least, this is the most important, can incoporate it with maven project.

Note: This [old closed StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse) mentions Window Builder Pro but it has not been updated for 2 years.

Comment: I tagged your question "gratis". If you need open source, please remove "gratis" and add "open-source" instead.

Comment: Pure Java or can it be Java FX?

Comment: I am opened to both. It looks like java FX is replacing Swing? Am I right? If JavaFX is the trend, then I would like to know more about JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, Java+Swing is like C#+Winforms and JavaFX is like WPF, if you know those better. JavaFX and WPF focus more on high DPI awareness.

Comment: I'm much tempted to close this as "too broad". We don't do list-type questions here, and all you gave as requirement is "for commercial use", "Java GUI design tool" and "Eclipse". Far from being sufficient IMHO: what features do you need? Please see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: @lzzy I edited the question, is that enough?

Comment: Of course, you need the result to run on Windows/Mac/Linux, right? Android and web not needed I guess?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Android and web not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at using [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) in combination with [e(fx)clipse](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-eclipse.htm). It should cover most of your requirements, and uses JavaFX, which is the toolkit Oracle currently leans towards for main Java usage. I would recommend against Windows Builder Pro, seeing how most of the toolkits it supports aren't actively developed anymore.

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. See the second Link
5. e(fx)clipse is actively maintained
6. Couldn't really test that
7. Yes
8. Yes
9. Yes (as part of eclipse or standalone)

Comment: Thanks! QUick question. I see that e(fx)clipse is a standalone project, can it incorporate with maven project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411524/how-to-combine-m2e-and-efxclipse